# Make a div appear but not move subsequent elements down

Tags: css, html

I need to make a div be visible (for use of it's background) even though it will not contain anything, but not push other elements down.

My layout looks like this:

```
/----------------a--------------------\
|-------------------------------------|
|________________b____________________|
```

The one labeled `a` needs to be visible but it will contain nothing. This is so the background image can make box `b` look like it has some gloss on the top, and box `b` will contain the text. However, the text in box `b` needs to start at the top of box `a`, *not* underneath it, which is the default behaviour.

So box `a` needs to act like it doesn't exist as far as layout goes, but needs to act like it exists for the purposes of background image.

To deomonstrate, this is what it looks like now, the default way:

```
/-------------------------------------\
|-------------------------------------|
|       there is some text here       |
|_______and more text down here_______|
```

but I want it to be

```
/-------------------------------------\
|-------there is some text here-------|
|_______and more text down here_______|
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't just want to add the background to `b`? `#b { background: url(image.png) repeat-x top;`

Comment: @Bazzz because b already has a repeating background image. `a` is a glossy overlay on that repeating one. I can't add the gloss directly to  b's bg image because it's repeat-xy and the gloss should only repeat-x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
#box {
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1; 
  width: 300px; 
  margin: 100px;
}

#boxa {
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: -1;
  top: -20px; 
  left: -10%; 
  width: 120%; 
  height: 50px; 
  background: #0f0;
}

#boxb {
  background: #eee; 
  height: 200px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
 <div id="boxa"></div>  
 <div id="boxb">text goes here</div>
<div>
```

I think you need to set the original stacking context on a wrapper so both boxes are in the same contest, then you can <strike>put box a in box b</strike> and negative z-index box a

**updated:** you don't need to put box in box b once they're both in the same staking context

### See working example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/4LfDN/) & updated to show boxes don't need to be nested : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/4LfDN/2/)

Comment: I would rather not position anything absolutely, this needs to resize with the page. However, it does what I want it to with this: http://codepad.org/sSWutTNX

Comment: OK, Thanks, glad it works - so one of those pngs is semi-transparent? you didn't say that in your question that would've made it easier ;)

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was implied since gloss is usually transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a `top` and `left` value combined with `position:absolute` should remove it from the document flow.

Comment: It's position needs to be caused by the previous elements but it's size needs to not affect the elements that come after it.

Comment: In which case, you probably need to apply the positioning to the following elements instead, e.g. `top:-10px;`

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do something similar to drop-shadows? Maybe this will help: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssdropshadows/

Comment: nope, like I said I'm doing gloss. CSS3 can do drop shadows for me :)

Comment: OK, I just thought the whole idea of offsetting one image over another was a similar set-up.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the style for that div

```
position:absolute;
```

Comment: This doesn't work because there is no text inside it, so I have to set the width, but I can't do width: 100% because that would make it overflow it's container and be 100% of the page, not it's container.

Comment: not sure you can easily do what you ask.... This method would require you to set the width and height of the div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="Position:Absolute; Z-Index: (HIGH Number to appear ON TOP, Low number to be concealed) >
</div>
```

Comment: See my comment on jimplode's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Either set the background on b (simple, don't know why you wouldn't), or absolutely position a inside b.

Edit: or, as clairesuzy says, put a after b, in the same container.

Answer (score 0):

See below. You can change the width / height to match the size of your background image.

http://jsfiddle.net/DhS3D/4/

HTML...

```
<div id="b">
  <div id="a"></div>
  This is some text.
</div>
```

CSS...

```
#a {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
#b {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #999;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using position absolute or relative depending on what it is