# The next element is not pushed down when overflow changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a read `more-less` button that hide and unhide content. But I have some issues because the next element is not pushed down when the first `div` increases.

This is the code:

```js
$("i").click(function(){
 $(".texto").toggleClass("hide-text");
});
```

```css
#masTexto {
position: relative;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.3)), to(rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8)), color-stop(.5, #333333));
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  color: #28f;
  margin-top : -10px;
  text-align: right;
}

i { cursor: pointer; }

.texto{
  height: 7em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
z-index: -1;
}

.hide-text{
overflow: initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="texto">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut placerat laoreet tellus, vitae aliquam nisl blandit ac. Nullam nec purus erat. Nam consectetur eget nisi et tempor. Maecenas condimentum tincidunt magna quis accumsan. Nam eu egestas erat. Integer
  condimentum sodales pretium. Fusce sit amet rhoncus mauris. Suspendisse feugiat consectetur enim malesuada feugiat.
  <br> Aliquam rutrum, quam quis sodales hendrerit, mi nisl pellentesque felis, sed ornare magna magna sit amet lacus. Donec ligula justo, varius eget tristique vel, ultricies eget nibh. Phasellus vel leo gravida, tempor orci volutpat, sodales ex. Donec ac
  arcu nulla. Sed feugiat imperdiet purus vel vehicula. In aliquam libero sed enim elementum, quis iaculis ante rutrum. Sed eget urna dictum, mattis felis vestibulum, scelerisque arcu. Fusce suscipit mi eu purus dapibus imperdiet. Fusce elit ante, semper
  placerat mi quis, laoreet euismod turpis.
</div>
<div id="masTexto">
  <br><br><i id="mas">Leer más</i>
</div>
```

I've changed `relative` to `absolute` positions and `overflow:initial` but nothing happens. Also I look for [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5649807/4987172) but doenst works for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with your actual code is that you're setting a fixed height to the `texto` element first.

```js
$("i").click(function(){
 $(".texto").toggleClass("hide-text");
});
```

```css
#masTexto {

  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.3)), to(rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8)), color-stop(.5, #333333));
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  color: #28f;
  margin-top : -10px;
  text-align: right;
}

i { cursor: pointer; }

.texto{
  height: 7em;
  overflow: hidden;
z-index: -1;
}

.hide-text{
overflow: initial;
height: 15em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="texto">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut placerat laoreet tellus, vitae aliquam nisl blandit ac. Nullam nec purus erat. Nam consectetur eget nisi et tempor. Maecenas condimentum tincidunt magna quis accumsan. Nam eu egestas erat. Integer
  condimentum sodales pretium. Fusce sit amet rhoncus mauris. Suspendisse feugiat consectetur enim malesuada feugiat.
  <br> Aliquam rutrum, quam quis sodales hendrerit, mi nisl pellentesque felis, sed ornare magna magna sit amet lacus. Donec ligula justo, varius eget tristique vel, ultricies eget nibh. Phasellus vel leo gravida, tempor orci volutpat, sodales ex. Donec ac
  arcu nulla. Sed feugiat imperdiet purus vel vehicula. In aliquam libero sed enim elementum, quis iaculis ante rutrum. Sed eget urna dictum, mattis felis vestibulum, scelerisque arcu. Fusce suscipit mi eu purus dapibus imperdiet. Fusce elit ante, semper
  placerat mi quis, laoreet euismod turpis.
</div>
<div id="masTexto">
  <br><br><i id="mas">Leer más</i>
</div>
```

This is with your actual code... however, there is a cleaner way to do this. This is just in case you do not mind having the initial text in a single line. You could use css `ellipsis`. Just check the fiddle and tweak the width. The only problem is that css does not support multiline `out of the box`, it requires js to do that. But see if the second solution fits on your case.

https://jsfiddle.net/9np4yatL/

Comment: Oh! amazing. I didn't  remember ellipsis but you're right. Possibly it could solve this problem also.